# Time complexity of find fun

Tags: c++11, vector, time, stl, c++14

Can you explain how find function works in STL C++ vector and what is its time complexity?

```
vector<int> v;

if(find(v.begin(),v.end(),element)==v.end())
do this;
else 
do this
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

In section "Possible implementation" you can figure out how it works. Details depend on the concrete implementation, which can be different. In any case `std::find()` will to have to iterate sequentially through your collection and that determines the time complexity. I.e. O(n).

Answer (score 3):

From [`[alg.find]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find)

> *Returns:* The first iterator `i` in the range `[first, last)` for which the following condition hold: `*i == value`.
>   Returns `last` if no such iterator is found.
>
> *Complexity:* At most `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate.

What that means is it will do a linear scan forward, until an value that compares equal to your `element` is reached.